# How do you turn columns into a matrix, filter on date and sort the indices?

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python and trying to learn. I have two columns of data that I would like to use to create a matrix. I am working with a lot of data but I created an example set below:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ['10/31/2019','12345','0','1'],['10/31/2019','54321','1','0'],['10/31/2019','43215','2','2'],
    ['10/31/2019','12346','0','1'],['10/31/2019','54322','1','0'],['9/28/2019','53215','3','3'],
    ['9/28/2019','73215','4','4'],['9/28/2019','13215','5','5'],['9/28/2019','42215','6','6'],
    ['9/28/2019','83215','7','7'],['9/28/2019','93215','8','8'],['9/28/2019','12215','9','9'],
    ['9/28/2019','73212','10','10'],['8/31/2019','22215','5','5'],['8/31/2019','56215','6','6']
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Date','AccountNo','BalanceTier','PriorMonthBalanceTier'])
df
```

This gives me the output below:

```
    Date    AccountNo BalanceTier   PriorMonthBalanceTier   
0   10/31/2019  12345     0           1
1   10/31/2019  54321     1           0
2   10/31/2019  43215     2           2
3   10/31/2019  12346     0           1
4   10/31/2019  54322     1           0
5   9/28/2019   53215     3           3
6   9/28/2019   73215     4           4
7   9/28/2019   13215     5           5
8   9/28/2019   42215     6           6
9   9/28/2019   83215     7           7
10  9/28/2019   93215     8           8
11  9/28/2019   12215     9           9
12  9/28/2019   73212     10         10
13  8/31/2019   22215     5           5
14  8/31/2019   56215     6           6
```

I then try to get a summary matrix off this data, where the columns are the `'BalanceTier'` and the rows are the `'PriorMonthBalanceTier'`. Each matrix is for a specific date. For example, if I filter on 10/31, the summary matrix would show me how accounts transitioned from one balance tier in 9/30 (PriorMonthBalanceTier) to another balance tier on 10/31 (BalanceTier). I tried the code below but it is giving me this error:

> TypeError: filter function returned a DataFrame, but expected a scalar bool

```
matrix = df.groupby('Date').filter(lambda x: x == '10/31/2019').groupby(['PriorMonthBalanceTier','BalanceTier']).size().unstack().fillna(0)
matrix
```

Although the result doesn't make sense, the code does run without the filter piece but the columns/rows are not sorted. For exmaple, the order of the rows/columns is 0, 1, 10,2,3,4... I would like it to be 0,1,2,3,4,...,10. Any help is appreciated since I am just starting out!

The output for 10/31/19 should be:
[image: output image]

Comment: Can you post an example of your desired output?

Comment: how do i add a table to stackoverflow? it won't let me do an image.

Comment: In the same way as you've added the output in your question or insert a screenshot as an image.

Comment: Thanks I was able to add it as a link in my description above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html)

Since your Tier variable are of string type, so the sorting will be `0 1 10 2 ...`. You should use `.astype(int)` to convert the data type to integer to get the sorting based on numeric value.

```
s1 = pd.Series(['2', '10', '0', '11' , '3', '1'])

print(s1.sort_values().values)
# ['0' '1' '10' '11' '2' '3']
print(s1.astype(int).sort_values().values)
# [ 0  1  2  3 10 11]
```

So here is the possible solution:

```
tbl = pd.crosstab(
    df['PriorMonthBalanceTier'].astype(int), 
    df['BalanceTier'].astype(int)
)
print(tbl)
# BalanceTier            0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
# PriorMonthBalanceTier
# 0                       0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 1                       2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 2                       0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 3                       0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 4                       0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 5                       0   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   0
# 6                       0   0   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   0
# 7                       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
# 8                       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
# 9                       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
# 10                      0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
```

### Apply filtering

The same technique can be applied on filtered columns, but you may find that levels `3 4 5 ...` disappeared because they are not in the filter dataset.

```
ind = (df['Date'].values == '10/31/2019')
tbl = pd.crosstab(
    df.loc[ind, 'PriorMonthBalanceTier'].astype(int), 
    df.loc[ind, 'BalanceTier'].astype(int), 
    dropna=False
)
print(tbl)
# BalanceTier            0  1  2
# PriorMonthBalanceTier
# 0                      0  2  0
# 1                      2  0  0
# 2                      0  0  1
```

So, if you want to keep all levels after filtering, you may need [`pd.Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html).

```
ind = (df['Date'].values == '10/31/2019')

col1 = df['PriorMonthBalanceTier'].astype(int)
col1 = pd.Categorical(col1[ind], col1.sort_values().unique())

col2 = df['BalanceTier'].astype(int)
col2 = pd.Categorical(col2[ind], col2.sort_values().unique())

tbl = pd.crosstab(
    col1, col2, 
    rownames=['PriorMonthBalanceTier'], 
    colnames=['BalanceTier'], 
    dropna=False
)
print(tbl)
# BalanceTier            0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
# PriorMonthBalanceTier
# 0                       0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 1                       2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 2                       0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 3                       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 4                       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 5                       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 6                       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 7                       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 8                       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 9                       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 10                      0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks for informing me about the crosstab function. It is exactly what I was looking for. I have one problem. I get an error when I run "col1 = pd.Categorical(col1[ind], col1.sort_values().unique())". The message says: C:\Program Files\Anaconda3_4_4_0\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:1: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.      AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'any'

Comment: Also what do you mean by keeping all levels after filtering?

Comment: @Anna What version of `pandas` are you using? For your 2nd question, you will get a crosstab of existing values only if you don't use `pd.Categorical`, please see my updated answer. ;)

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying. I am using Python 3.6.1. Could that be causing the error message?

Comment: @Anna Not sure, do you get any error if you just run `col1[ind]` or `col1.sort_values().unique()`

Answer (score 1):

Did you think of this?

```
df.groupby('Date') \
  .filter(lambda grp: grp.Date.iloc[0]=="10/31/2019") \
  .groupby(['PriorMonthBalanceTier','BalanceTier'] \
  .size().unstack().fillna(0).astype(int)

BalanceTier            0  1  2
PriorMonthBalanceTier         
0                      0  2  0
1                      2  0  0
2                      0  0  1
```

**Edit:** So it's simpler:

```
df[df.Date.eq("10/31/2019")] \ 
      .groupby(['PriorMonthBalanceTier','BalanceTier']) \ 
      .size().unstack().fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Comment: One more question. What if I don't know the position of 10/31/19, i.e. can't use iloc? I would instead like to filter based on the column value 10/31/19. Can you do that filter as part of the groupby function?

Comment: All the 'Date' column values  have the same date in a 'grp'.

Comment: The 'filter' and first 'groupby' are not really necessary. See the edited code above.

Comment: Thanks. The simpler solution works if I break it into two parts.